# Origami (Quartz composer) Set variable

Tags: javascript, quartz-composer, origami

how to set a dynamic variable that can keep changing? like javascript "var x=1" Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I understand your question correctly.

Probably, you wanted to create a variable for a loop:

```
for(x = 0; x < 11; x++) { ... }
```

There is two ways to solve this task.

[image]

I used "Circle" patch for a dynamic test ("Clear" patch is for filling BG with black color).
You need to place an "Iterator Variables" patch inside "Iterator" (by double-clicking "Iterator"). For "Iterator Variables" patch assign **Publish Outputs** ("Current Index") with right mouse button (slot turns green). You'll see that "Current Index" output on Iterator's patch body. Also you need a "Math" patch with expression a/10 (a = "Current Index").

Connect and setup Low Frequency Oscillator (LFO), Iterator, Math and Circle as shown on the picture.

Or simply use "JavaScript" patch with the following code:

[image]